# Why do I get an error requesting template arguments when I'm instantiating a generic object?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm getting the following error: error C2955: 'MagicBag': use of class template requires template argument list. This occurs at line 5 of my main class, which is as follows:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MagicBag.h"

int main() {
    MagicBag<int> mb1;//this is where I'm getting the error
    mb1.insert(5);
    mb1.insert(4);
    return 0;
}
```

I've looked into this error (for hours now) and as far as I can tell, it's because I'm not giving the declaration template arguments. But isn't that exactly what I'm doing by putting "int" in the diamond operator? I'm trying to make sure my insert method works properly, but I can't seem to even properly declare a MagicBag object. Below is the MagicBag.h file.

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T> struct node {
   T value;
   node<T> * next;
};

template<class T> class MagicBag {
public:
MagicBag() {
    first = NULL;
}

~MagicBag() {
}

void insert(T item) {
    size++;
    node<T> a;
    a.value = item;
    if (first == NULL) {
        a.next = NULL;
    }
    else {
        a.next = first;//set a.next to point to node pointed to by first
    }
    first = &a;//set first to point to a
}
private:
node<T> * first;
int size = 0;
};
```

I've tried about everything at this point, putting T in diamond operators just about anywhere I could think to do so including in the MagicBag.h file. I know this is a common problem (plenty of results on google and this site) and I should be able to manage it on my own, but for the life of me I don't understand what I'm missing. Why is my declaration of a MagicBag object insufficient? For other people (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966447/c-template-generics-template-argument-list), it seems to be an issue of them calling Node instead of Node(T) (I can't get the T in diamond operators to show up), but I don't see any instances of me doing that in my code. Trying to put T in diamond operators in the constructor also does nothing to fix the issue, so for the life of me I'm stumped. Thank you for any help anyone may be willing to offer.

Comment: Get rid of the `stdafx.h`.  It causes more harm than good for beginner programmers.  I wouldn't be shocked if this header has a role in what is going on.  As you can see [here](http://ideone.com/Chn5eZ), I don't get an error.

Comment: When I did that, I got an error about my #include "MagicBag.h" statement being skipped because I was missing a stdafx.h import. I'll update my code to include my insert function, in case I'm missing something there. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Go to your project settings and turn off the precompiled headers.  As I said, it is a hindrance for beginners.  No C++ book, unless it is specifically one for Visual C++, will you see "stdafx.h" anywhere in the examples.

Comment: Okay I did that and that got rid of that error, however I'm still getting the error requesting template arguments.

Comment: Take the code I posted at the link as-is.  Don't add or remove lines.  Does it compile?

Comment: ok.  Now take the code that consists of MagicBag.h, remove the lines that are there now, and add the lines from the code that compiled that makes up the header.  An `#include` is merely a copy / paste of a file within the source code, so there shouldn't be any difference.

Comment: Okay, I just did that, but I'm still getting the same error now. I double checked the precompiled headers were set to off but I'm still getting error C2955.

Comment: It's saying that the error is occuring at the return statement in the main function.

Comment: What is the error?  And I just took your code in Visual Studio 2015, and got no error whatsoever when creating the header file.  Are you sure you don't have another old version of MagicBag.h hanging around, and this version is the one that's being included (instead of the new version)?

Comment: Here's the output: 1>c:\users\build a\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\cs3100project1\cs3100project1\magicbag.cpp(5): error C2955: 'MagicBag': use of class template requires template argument list

Comment: I don't have any other versions of my header file, so it doesn't seem to be that. I appreciate your help, but the project isn't due for two weeks so I can just go to office hours tomorrow. I'll close the topic now.

Comment: Here is what the header [should look like](http://rextester.com/LVZ82163).  The main program should look like [this](http://rextester.com/COKU55285).  This in Visual Studio 2015 gave no errors with precompiled headers turned off.

Comment: That's exactly what I have and I'm still getting the same error.